How to obfuscate Android AOSP system app code?
Does anyone know if it's possible to obfuscate Android AOSP or LineageOS Android 13 system app java code or resources for apps like SystemUI, Settings, TvSettings, framework-res.apk if building from source code?
Proguard seems mostly for Gradle apps, not sure if it can be added correctly for apps with Android.bp files. If so how to add it for the above system apps? And will the built firmware still be bootable?
AndResGuard seems to be only for Gradle or 3rd party apps.
There seems to be no way to obfuscate resources in the system apps' res folder.

The question is too vast. Would advise to split it into one-by-one.

System apps do use proguard in AOSP as well. The Android.bp can have proguard flags file defined with the optimized attrib
Take a look here: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-14.0.0_r1:packages/apps/Launcher3/Android.bp;l=202

Thanks, it seems to work for SystemUI java files. Do you know of any free way to obfuscate res folder png files, strings.xml perhaps? I only find AndResGuard but it is only for Gradle apps and not for system apps with Android.bp
